# Profiled litz wire manufacture

Tags: litz-wire

How is profiled Litz wire manufactured?

Is it winded in the shape, or a round one passes thought conforming process?

Comment: You may be best served just by asking a manufacturer.

Comment: I don't think they want to tell that.

Comment: You'll be surprised. Remember, they're catering to engineers, who need to know the exact characteristics of their wires.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elektrisola.com/hf-litz-wire-litz/products/profiling.html This OEM shows basic materials and shape but not how it’s put together to increase fill factor.

Each strand is enamel coated then twisted into a form and bonded with several plastics in a composite bond.

Answer (score 0):

The machines that produce litz wire inherently produce a circular cross-section from the bobbins which weave in and out around a circular path, so I strongly suspect that it is post-formed. The process is similar to producing [textile shoelaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmn34RZ89ks).